# Identify NULL and assign bitmap

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

table1

```
u_a_id  e_id   e_nm    e_val    e_seq
1       104    test    100      4
1       102    test2   x        2
1       102    test2   (null)   1
1       104    test    (null)   1

2       102    test2   (null)   2
2       102    test2   (null)   1
2       104    test    101      1
2       104    test    102      2
```

I need to first sort by `e_id`, `e_seq` for each u_a_id and identify each `(null)` as 1 and then create a bitmap as below.

For ex.

- u_a_id = 1 - first e_id = 102, e_seq = 1, e_val = (null), so assign it 1
- u_a_id = 1 - first e_id = 102, e_seq = 2, e_val = x, so assign it 0
- u_a_id = 1 - first e_id = 104, e_seq = 1, e_val = (null), so assign it 1
- u_a_id = 1 - first e_id = 104, e_seq = 4, e_val = 100, so assign it 0

So, for u_a_id = 1, add a new row - EMPTY = 1010

The output would be:

```
u_a_id  e_id   e_nm    e_val    e_seq
1       104    test    100      4
1       102    test2   x        2
1       102    test2   (null)   1
1       104    test    (null)   1
1       (null) EMPTY   1010     (null)

2       102    test2   (null)   2
2       102    test2   (null)   1
2       104    test    101      1
2       104    test    102      2
2       (null) EMPTY   1100     (null)
```

Is there a way in Oracle SQL to do it?

Comment: Is this difficult to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `LISTAGG` for string aggregation and `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT U_A_ID, E_ID
 ,CASE WHEN GROUPING_ID(U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ) = 15 
       THEN 'EMPTY' 
       ELSE E_NM END AS E_NM
 ,CASE WHEN GROUPING_ID(U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ) = 15 
       THEN LISTAGG(NVL2(E_VAL, '1', '0'),'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY E_ID DESC, E_SEQ DESC) 
       ELSE E_VAL END AS E_VAL
 ,E_SEQ
FROM E
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ), (U_A_ID))
ORDER BY U_A_ID, E_ID, E_SEQ;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6b8e7bc091921e28d38700ef89d4dcb9)**

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you asked, creating a text string with 1s and 0s.
Note that the UNION was put there simply to replicate the expected result row mixed with the data. You can remove the UNION and the bit of SQL after it.

It is just as easy to create a proper numeric bitmap instead of the text string.

Setup:

```
create table e(
  u_a_id integer,
  e_id integer,
  e_nm varchar2(10),
  e_val varchar2(10),
  e_seq integer
);

INSERT INTO E(U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ) VALUES (1,102,'test2','x',2);
INSERT INTO E(U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ) VALUES (1,102,'test2',NULL,1);
INSERT INTO E(U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ) VALUES (1,104,'test','100',4);
INSERT INTO E(U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ) VALUES (1,104,'test',NULL,1);
INSERT INTO E(U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ) VALUES (2,102,'test2',NULL,1);
INSERT INTO E(U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ) VALUES (2,102,'test2',NULL,2);
INSERT INTO E(U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ) VALUES (2,104,'test','101',1);
INSERT INTO E(U_A_ID, E_ID, E_NM, E_VAL, E_SEQ) VALUES (2,104,'test','102',2);
```

Query:

```
with x as(
  -- This gets the rows with a "row number" within each U_A_ID group
  select e.*,row_number() over (PARTITION BY u_a_id ORDER BY e_id, e_seq) R from e
),
y as(
  -- This produces the bit, as a character, based on the E_VAL column
  select x.u_a_id, x.e_id, x.e_seq, nvl2(x.e_val, '1', '0') as bit from x
),
z as(
  -- This concatenates the bits, in the same reversed order that you provided
  select u_a_id, listagg(bit, '') within group (order by e_id desc, e_seq desc) bits from y group by u_a_id
)
select u_a_id, null as e_id, 'EMPTY' as e_nm, to_char(bits) as e_val, null as e_seq from z
union
select u_a_id, e_id, e_nm, e_val, e_seq from e
order by u_a_id, e_id nulls last, e_seq
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The following produces your "bitmap":

```
select distinct t2.u_a_id,
    (select case when t1.e_val is null then '1' else '0' end as [text()]
     from table1 as t1
     where t1.u_a_id = t2.u_a_id
     order by u_a_id, e_id, e_seq
     for xml path ('')
    ) as bitmap
from table1 as t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest will be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM E -- Get the unchanged records
UNION ALL
-- And add the new rows:
SELECT U_A_ID
     , NULL
     , 'EMPTY'
     , listagg(NVL2(E_VAL, 0, 1),'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e_id, e_seq)
     , NULL
  FROM e
 GROUP BY u_a_id
ORDER BY 1,2 nulls last, 5 nulls last -- Order to get your desired order
```